# I have stored image to inputstream from html,so i want to store the inputstream to folder in my drive

Tags: java, jsp, inputstream

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("barcodePhtotoVen");

inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
```

How to write this using outputstream to folder/file in my computer drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope following code snippet help you

**Update :**

```
 OutputStream out = null;
 InputStream filecontent = null;

 try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File("destination_file_path"));
    filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException f) {

} finally {
  if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Earlier code I tested on mine system, perfectly worked. Please try mine updated code. I just tested on mine system  and its working fine too.

*Resources* : [Hope this knowledge sharing help you.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)

Thanks.

Comment: showing up blank file

Comment: I just updated mine code. How it works please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an InputStream and do not use an OutputStream.  Part has a [write(String) method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write(java.lang.String)) which writes the part directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> I have stored image to inputstream

No you haven't. You haven't stored the image anywhere, let alone to an input stream, which is a contradiction in terms. You need to read *from* the input stream and write to a disk file.